# Encoding a string into base64

Tags: c, base64

I'm trying to create a simple HTTP client. In order to make one that is standard compliant, I must be able to extract user information from a URI and convert it to base64 and send it via an authentication header to the server. I created this demo program to test my progress on this function I've made. Does this program seem sufficient? Is there any major flaws with it? You can see the demo [here](http://pastebin.com/zsyvk3NR).

```
char *base64encode(char *input) {
    int len = strlen(input), padding = (len % 3)?3 - (len % 3):0, n, xlen = 0;
    size_t bitlen = len * 8;
    uint8_t *x = malloc(((int)(bitlen / 24) * 4) + ((padding)?4:0)), i, o;
    for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        switch (n % 3) {
            case 0:
                i = (uint8_t)(input[n] >> 2);
                x[xlen++] = i;
                break;
            case 1:
                i = (uint8_t)((input[n-1] & 3) << 4);
                o = (uint8_t)((input[n] & 240) >> 4);
                x[xlen++] = i | o;
                break;
            case 2:
                i = (uint8_t)((input[n-1] & 15) << 2);
                o = (uint8_t)((input[n] & 192) >> 6);
                x[xlen++] = i | o;
                i = (uint8_t)(input[n] & 63);
                x[xlen++] = i;
                break;
        }
        if ((len - n) == ((padding==2)?2:3) && padding > 0) {
            n++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (padding == 2) {
        i = (uint8_t)(input[n] >> 2);
        x[xlen++] = i;
        i = (uint8_t)((input[n] & 3) << 4);
        x[xlen++] = i;
    } else if (padding == 1) {
        i = (uint8_t)(input[n] >> 2);
        x[xlen++] = i;
        i = (uint8_t)((input[n] & 3) << 4);
        o = (uint8_t)((input[n+1] & 240) >> 4);
        x[xlen++] = i | o;
        i = (uint8_t)((input[n+1] & 15) << 2);
        x[xlen++] = i;
    }
    const char *index = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    char *returnString = malloc((int)((bitlen / 24) + padding) * 4 + 1);
    for (n = 0; n < ((int)(bitlen / 24) * 4) + ((padding)?4:0) - padding; n++) {
        returnString[n] = index[x[n]];
    }
    free(x);
    for (;padding > 0; padding--) {
        returnString[n++] = '=';
    }
    returnString[n] = '\0';
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain? I'm not much of an expert in C.

Comment: ASCII but I don't see a reason why UTF-8 wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bugs

I found a couple of bugs in your program.

1. Your end-of-string handling is off for input strings smaller than 3 bytes.  This is because your end-of-string check is too late to stop the first byte from being processed.  So for the input `"a"`, your function returns `"YA=="` instead of `"YQ=="`.  See below for a solution for this problem.
2. If the input string contains characters with the high bit set, such as what could happen with UTF-8 input, then your function handles that incorrectly.  The culprit is that you use signed chars, and do bit shifting with those signed chars.  Imagine that `input[n]` is `0x80` here:

   ```
           i = (uint8_t)(input[n] >> 2);
   ```

   What you would like to be calculated for `i` is `0x20`.  But what you will actually calculate for `i` is `0xe0`.  Later you will use `0xe0` as an index into your string and it will overflow the bounds.  You can fix this by moving your cast to the right place:

   ```
           i = ((uint8_t)input[n] >> 2);
   ```

### One pass instead of two

Right now you are building up an array `x` of indices and then you use a second pass to convert the `x` array into the base64 string.  It would be quicker and simpler to just build up `returnString` directly and get rid of the intermediary `x` array.  For example, instead of:

```
        case 0:
            i = (uint8_t)(input[n] >> 2);
            x[xlen++] = i;
            break;
```

You could write:

```
        case 0:
            i = (uint8_t)(input[n] >> 2);
            returnString[xlen++] = index[i];
            break;
```

### Simplifying the loop termination check

Right now, you have a complicated check that looks like this:

```
    if ((len - n) == ((padding==2)?2:3) && padding > 0) {
        n++;
        break;
    }
```

As mentioned earlier, this check was also insufficient for strings smaller than 3 bytes.  A simpler way of doing this is just to modify `len` to round down to the nearest multiple of 3 before starting the loop.  This does exactly what you wanted and also handles smaller than 3 byte strings:

```
    len -= (len % 3);
    for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        switch (n % 3) {
            ...
        }
        // Complicated check removed.
    }
```

### Getting rid of the switch

Once you have made `len` a multiple of three (above), you can actually get rid of the switch statement.  Instead of iterating over every byte of the input, you can now iterate by three bytes at a time and do all three switch cases one after the other.

### Confusing bitmask constants

Your code is correct, but I had a hard time trying to figure out what some of your constants meant.  For example:

```
            o = (uint8_t)((input[n] & 240) >> 4);
```

would make a lot more sense if you used the hex value like this:

```
            o = (uint8_t)((input[n] & 0xf0) >> 4);
```

Now I know you are taking the top 4 bits and shifting them down.

### Reusing common code

After the main loop when you handle the two possible padding cases, most of the code for the `padding == 2` case is also done in the `padding == 1` case.  You can combine some of the common code together so that you don't repeat the code twice.  This is a matter of preference though, so what you have is fine if you find it more readable.

### Other things

- You should check the return value of malloc.
- Your input argument is unmodified so you can make it a const argument.
- You don't really need both `i` and `o` although if you like them to be separate variables you can.

---

### Putting it all together

Here's what your code would look like after all my suggested changes (and a lot of other tweaks that are stylistic/optional):

```
char *base64encode(const char *input)
{
    int      len      = strlen(input);
    int      leftover = len % 3;
    char    *ret      = malloc(((len/3) * 4) + ((leftover)?4:0) + 1);
    int      n        = 0;
    int      outlen   = 0;
    uint8_t  i        = 0;
    uint8_t *inp      = (uint8_t *) input;
    const char *index = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                        "0123456789+/";

    if (ret == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Convert each 3 bytes of input to 4 bytes of output.
    len -= leftover;
    for (n = 0; n < len; n+=3) {
        i = inp[n] >> 2;
        ret[outlen++] = index[i];

        i  = (inp[n]   & 0x03) << 4;
        i |= (inp[n+1] & 0xf0) >> 4;
        ret[outlen++] = index[i];

        i  = ((inp[n+1] & 0x0f) << 2);
        i |= ((inp[n+2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
        ret[outlen++] = index[i];

        i  = (inp[n+2] & 0x3f);
        ret[outlen++] = index[i];
    }

    // Handle leftover 1 or 2 bytes.
    if (leftover) {
        i = (inp[n] >> 2);
        ret[outlen++] = index[i];

        i = (inp[n]   & 0x03) << 4;
        if (leftover == 2) {
            i |= (inp[n+1] & 0xf0) >> 4;
            ret[outlen++] = index[i];

            i  = ((inp[n+1] & 0x0f) << 2);
        }
        ret[outlen++] = index[i];
        ret[outlen++] = '=';
        if (leftover == 1)
            ret[outlen++] = '=';
    }
    ret[outlen] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours on end working on this and I was trying to think of a mathematical way to generate the length of bytes before padding. I think that's where I went off track, and your method makes so much sense.